# Golang docker library - mounting host directory volumes

Tags: docker, go

How do I perform the equivalent of:

```
docker run -v /host/path:/container/path image:tag
```

from Go using the official docker client package?

I've tried different [Mounts](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container#HostConfig) and [Volumes](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container#Config) options within the HostOption and ConfigOption structs for the [client.ContainerCreate() function](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ContainerCreate), but can't quite figure it out.

In particular, the `Volumes` member (of type `map[string]struct{}`) is particularly hard to figure out how to use, and I can't find any documentation on what values are supposed to be present within the struct.

Code to demonstrate my problem:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    //"github.com/docker/docker/api/types/mount"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/stdcopy"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func getThisDir() string {
    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return dir
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Creating client")
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    image := "ubuntu:18.04"
    hostPath := getThisDir()
    containerPath := "/host_files"

    log.Printf("             Image: %s\n", image)
    log.Printf("         Host Path: %s\n", hostPath)
    log.Printf("    Container Path: %s\n", containerPath)

    ctx := context.Background()
    cli.NegotiateAPIVersion(ctx)

    log.Println("Creating container")
    var cont container.ContainerCreateCreatedBody
    if cont, err = cli.ContainerCreate(
        context.Background(),
        &container.Config{
            Image:      image,
            Entrypoint: []string{"/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -la " + containerPath},
            Volumes: map[string]struct{}{
                hostPath: {},
            },
        },
        &container.HostConfig{
            Runtime: "runsc",
            /*
                Mounts: []mount.Mount{
                    mount.Mount{
                        Type:   mount.TypeVolume,
                        Source: hostPath,
                        Target: containerPath,
                    },
                },
            */
        },
        nil,
        "TEST_CONTAINER",
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        log.Println("Cleaning up")
        if err := cli.ContainerRemove(
            context.Background(),
            cont.ID,
            types.ContainerRemoveOptions{
                Force:         true,
                RemoveVolumes: true,
            },
        ); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    log.Println("Starting container")
    if err = cli.ContainerStart(
        context.Background(),
        cont.ID,
        types.ContainerStartOptions{},
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println("Waiting for container to exit")
    waitOk, waitErr := cli.ContainerWait(
        ctx,
        cont.ID,
        container.WaitConditionNotRunning,
    )
    select {
    case <-waitOk:
        log.Println("Container exited normally!")
    case err = <-waitErr:
        log.Println("Error waiting")
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("Should be done!")

    logOutput, err := cli.ContainerLogs(
        ctx,
        cont.ID,
        types.ContainerLogsOptions{
            ShowStdout: true,
            ShowStderr: true,
            Follow:     false,
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println("Container output:")
    stdcopy.StdCopy(os.Stdout, os.Stderr, logOutput)
}
```

Compiling and running this yields the output:

```
2019/04/16 20:42:21 Creating client
2019/04/16 20:42:21              Image: ubuntu:18.04
2019/04/16 20:42:21          Host Path: /home/user/go/src/test
2019/04/16 20:42:21     Container Path: /host_files
2019/04/16 20:42:21 Creating container
2019/04/16 20:42:22 Starting container
2019/04/16 20:42:22 Waiting for container to exit
2019/04/16 20:42:22 Container exited normally!
2019/04/16 20:42:22 Should be done!
2019/04/16 20:42:22 Container output:
ls: cannot access '/host_files': No such file or directory
2019/04/16 20:42:22 Cleaning up
```

If you uncomment the mount-related lines, you get this output instead:

```
2019/04/16 20:23:32 Creating client
2019/04/16 20:23:32              Image: ubuntu:18.04
2019/04/16 20:23:32          Host Path: /home/user/go/src/test
2019/04/16 20:23:32     Container Path: /host_files
2019/04/16 20:23:32 Creating container
panic: Error response from daemon: create /home/user/go/src/test: "/home/user/go/src/test" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/user/go/src/test/container.go:66 +0xb0c
```

The error message doesn't make sense, since I *am* using an absolute path. Maybe I should reread the documentation for `ContainerCreate`.

### Update 1

[The docker engine API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ContainerCreate) contains more details about Volumes - I'm beginning to think that I'm mistaken about how `docker -v /host/path:/container/path` works - perhaps that is actually a bind mount and not a volume mount.

### Update 2

[Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) FTW I guess. Removing the `Volumes` settings, adding the `Mounts` back in and changing the `Type` to `mount.TypeBind` made it work:

```
2019/04/16 20:53:18 Creating client
2019/04/16 20:53:18              Image: ubuntu:18.04
2019/04/16 20:53:18          Host Path: /home/user/go/src/test
2019/04/16 20:53:18     Container Path: /host_files
2019/04/16 20:53:18 Creating container
2019/04/16 20:53:18 Starting container
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Waiting for container to exit
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Container exited normally!
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Should be done!
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Container output:
total XXXX
drwxr-xr-x  7 1000 1000     4096 Apr 17 03:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root     4096 Apr 17 03:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000    10390 Apr 16 12:16 Gopkg.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000     1021 Apr 16 12:16 Gopkg.toml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000 12433827 Apr 17 03:53 container
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000     2421 Apr 17 03:51 container.go
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Cleaning up
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `Volumes` settings, adding the `Mounts` back in and changing the `Type` to `mount.TypeBind` made it work:

```
2019/04/16 20:53:18 Creating client
2019/04/16 20:53:18              Image: ubuntu:18.04
2019/04/16 20:53:18          Host Path: /home/user/go/src/test
2019/04/16 20:53:18     Container Path: /host_files
2019/04/16 20:53:18 Creating container
2019/04/16 20:53:18 Starting container
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Waiting for container to exit
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Container exited normally!
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Should be done!
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Container output:
total XXXX
drwxr-xr-x  7 1000 1000     4096 Apr 17 03:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root     4096 Apr 17 03:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000    10390 Apr 16 12:16 Gopkg.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000     1021 Apr 16 12:16 Gopkg.toml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1000 1000 12433827 Apr 17 03:53 container
-rw-r--r--  1 1000 1000     2421 Apr 17 03:51 container.go
2019/04/16 20:53:19 Cleaning up
```

Sigh.

The only thing I'm not 100% sure about is if `docker -v /host/path:/container/path image:tag` *is actually* a bind mount, or not.

Comment: Yes, it is a bind mount (because it references a specific host-side path) and not a named-volume mount.